# Volume of solid... bounded by $y=x^2+1, x=1, x=7, \text{and}\:y=5$ around the y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Using Geogebra the following is a visual of the problem:
[image]

Using washer method I got the following:
$$V=\int_{2}^{5}\pi[(\sqrt{y-1})^2-1^2] dy=\frac{9}{2}\pi$$
Questions:

1. Is this correct? I don't recall dealing with these type of problems when I took calculus since such problems would have either $x=0$ or $y=0$ as bounds.
2. What's the set-up if we were to use cylindrical method? I have $$V=\int_{1}^{2} 2\pi x(x^2+1-1) dx=\int_{1}^{2} 2\pi x(x^2) dx=\frac{15}{2}\pi$$ but this doesn't match what I got using the washer method. However, if I don't subtract $1$ in the washer method I also get $\frac{15}{2}\pi$.
3. Whats the point of $x=7$?

Comment: For question 1) and 2), consider what I've written in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132391/volume-of-revolution-found-by-rotating-the-region-bounded-by-x-y2-and-x-1-y/3132416?r=SearchResults#3132416) (it's a different solid of revolution, but the thought process is the same: for each $x$ / $y$ value, find a surface area, then integrate that).

Comment: How is the vertical line $x=7$ used to form that region? Can't you see that it's not part of anything? It's just a piece of useless information. Other than that, your solution seems to be correct.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Yeah, that's what I was thinking which didn't make sense why its part of the problem. Which part of my solution?

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, I'm reading it.

Comment: @Arthur I think I got it. Is the answer $\frac{7}{6}\pi$?

Comment: For the washers method, your solution is correct. Not for the shells method: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+2+*+pi+*+x+*+(5-(x%5E2%2B1))+dx+from+1+to+2

Comment: @MichaelRybkin I found my mistake. I forgot to distribute the $x$ and calculated $(4x-x^2)$. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Quick question. Why would the following be wrong: $(\sqrt{y-1}-1)^2$ using the washer method.

Comment: That would be wrong. You're subtracting disks that have volumes. Each disks has the volume $\pi [r(x)]^2 dx$ where $dx$ is an infinitesimal width. $\sqrt{y-1}-1$ would be one disk with that radius. In that case, you would be using the disk method, not the washers method.

Comment: I guess for a moment if you ignore about washer method, I do not recall as it is several years now, what you got is a variable(area) hollow cylindrical disc. The formula is pi*(R^2 -r^2)*h. The R is variable, root(y-1) and r is 1. and you know the height.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct setup for the washer method, at least regarding the region in your graph.

For the cylindrical shell method, look closer at that graph - the boundaries of a vertical slice of the region are a lower bound at $y=x^2+1$ and an upper bound at $y=5$. The integral becomes
$$V = \int_1^2 2\pi x(5-(x^2+1))\,dx$$

About that $x=7$? I'm stumped. That gives us another bounded region above $y=5$, below $y=x^2+1$, and to the right of $x=7$. It's much larger than the region you were dealing with, and ignores the $x=1$ boundary instead. Want a region bounded by all four lines/curves? That will be one of the unbounded regions, resulting in infinite volume. It's not just useless information - it actively confuses everything else.

Comment: I had that initially, I just forgot to distribute the x. Thanks.